# Get child vertex that match search

Tags: gremlin, opensearch, amazon-neptune

I'm implementing a graph database on ASWS Neptune and I'm using as well AWS OpenSearch to allow me perform a full text search.

I want to get all the child vertex that match a property. (In this case get all documents)

I did the following:

```
g.V( folderId )
 .emit()
 .repeat( in().dedup() )
 .in()
 .hasLabel( "document" )
 .valueMap()
 .by( unfold() )
 .toList();
```

This will return all documents that are in that folder and sub-folders as well.

Now I did this to only return the documents that are in that folder/subfolder that match a `name`.

```
g.withSideEffect( "Neptune#fts.endpoint", "..." )
 .V( folderId )
 .has( "name", "Neptune#fts " + name + "*" )
 .emit()
 .repeat( in().dedup() )
 .in()
 .hasLabel( "document" )
 .valueMap()
 .by( unfold() )
 .toList();
```

It returns a empty result but if I remove the `folderId` it returns all the documents that match that name.

Any way to only return the ones that match the name and are on that folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without some sort of sample data it is hard to give you a query that will satisfy your requirements but the likely reason you are getting an empty result is that you are not traversing to any child records to apply your `name` search.  Let's look at this section of the query:

```
g.withSideEffect( "Neptune#fts.endpoint", "..." )
 .V( folderId )
 .has( "name", "Neptune#fts " + name + "*" )
```

This is saying "Find me a vertex with an `id=folderId` and a `name like name*`.  This will only return a value if both of these conditions are true, which I suspect are not in this scenario.

If you are looking to find all child `documents` for a specific vertex id that start with `name*` then you will want to do something more like:

```
g.withSideEffect( "Neptune#fts.endpoint", "..." )
 .V( folderId )  //Find a vertex with folderId
 .emit() //Emit the vertices
 .repeat( in().dedup()) //Repeatedly go out the in edges until there are no more
 .hasLabel( "document" ) //Filter to only document labels
 .has( "name", "Neptune#fts " + name + "*" ) //Filter to find things with "name*"
 .valueMap()
 .by( unfold() )
 .toList();
```

Additionally, due to how Neptune indexes data ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/feature-overview-data-model.html#feature-overview-storage-indexing-gremlin)) will perform better if you can specify the label(s) for the `in()` edges such as `in('parent')`.